# Fill field with autoincrement values in admin inline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following code:

```
class Question (models.Model):

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Choice (models.Model):

     question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
     number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
     choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import Question, Choice

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question_text']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

and I want to add autoincrement number field. While adding Question I have tab where I add Choices. There is a number field. By default it is empty. I want to fill it by automatic numbers starting from 1. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess that you want to save the order of the `Choice`s?

You could override the method [save_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related) in the `QuestionAdmin` class, which is responsable to save all the related objects, just iterate over the objets setting the order attribute.

Comment: No, I want to number a number field of Choices. To set default field value of number field. And after clicking 'add another choice" to set value of number field to 4,5 etc.